# How to use IF statement inside a promise response to render React components

Tags: reactjs, express, promise, react-router, axios

I am using passport local mongoose to register users inside of my database. I am using react-router for client-side rendering. Inside of my Register.jsx React component, I am calling the following function once the username and password inputs have been filled and the "Register" button is clicked:

```
    function submitUser() {
        Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/register", {
            username: registerUsername,
            password: registerPassword
        }).then(function(res) {
                if (res.data === "User already exists") {
                    history.push("/register");
                } else if (res.data === "User created") {
                    history.push("/registerconfirmed");
                }
            });
    }
```

On the server side, here is the code to handle that post request:

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, async (err, doc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (doc) res.send("User already exists");
        if (!doc) {

            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

            const newUser = new User({
                username: req.body.username,
                password: hashedPassword
            });
            await newUser.save();
            res.send("User created");
        }
```

I have confirmed that new users are successfully added and that existing users are not. The response I am getting on the client side can also log the correct response from the server.

The problem is that the IF statement I have set up is not working. Regardless of the success/failure of registering a new user, the Register.jsx React component simply refreshes. I want to reload the Register.jsx component if unsuccessful, but I want to render the RegisterConfirmed.jsx component when the new user is successfully registered. How can I correctly achieve this?

Comment: you are not using `comparison` operator. it should be `if (res.data === "User already exists")`

Comment: Just a typo, you assign instead of compare.

Comment: I corrected that typo and updated my question, but that doesn't change anything in my app. I am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that ONLY `history.push("/registerconfirmed")` is called when the registration is successful? Is the correct component specified under that path in the router?

Comment: @SebastianAmmon That is the correct component, but the problem is that it is NOT being called when the registration is successful. I have tried replacing `history.push("/registerconfirmed")` with `console.log("Good to go!")` and that does not get logged either.

Comment: @cchau what does `res.data` look like?

Comment: @SebastianAmmon when I console log `res.data` I either get "User already exists" or "User created"

Comment: @cchau if you say that is the case, then I don't see why `history.push("/registerconfirmed")` is not called. The code looks fine in your `.then(...)`

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1:**

```
    function submitUser() {
            Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/register", {
                username: registerUsername,
                password: registerPassword
            }).then(function(res) {
                    if (res.data === "User already exists") {
                        return <Register />
                    } else if (res.data === "User created") {
                        return <Registerconfirmed />
                    }
            });
    }
```

**Method 2:**
you can do it with useState

```
    import { useState } from 'react';
    function submitUser() {
            const [status, setStatus] = useState(NULL);
            Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/register", {
                username: registerUsername,
                password: registerPassword
            }).then(function(res) { setPage(res.data) });
    return ( 
          {
           status === "User already exists" ? 
              <Register /> : status === "User created" ? 
              <Registerconfirmed /> : NULL
          }
    )
    }
```